# Animation in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css

I would like to put simple animation in my lightning component.
I tried to use an existing CSS from this framwork :
https://github.com/IanLunn/Hover

The effect that i want to use is Grow

List of effects: https://hovercss.pagecloud.com/

CMP:

```
<div class="hvr-grow">
test
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.THIS .hvr-grow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
}
.THIS.hvr-grow:hover, .THIS.hvr-grow:focus, .THIS.hvr-grow:active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

I tested this css(without ".THIS") in a simple HTML page and it is working.
But here it is not working.
Is it even possible to do something like that ? 
if yes, how can i should fix that ?
if no, is there is an other solution to use animation ?

thank you

Comment: Be careful about adding or not spaces between `.THIS` and `.hvr-grow`. Indeed, if your `hvr-grow` div is the main div of your lightning component, salesforce will consider it as the `.THIS` also. So, you should remove the space between `.THIS` and `.hvr-grow` like this: `.THIS.hvr-grow{ `

Comment: thank you Martin its seems that there is a need for a space . I add one between ".THIS" and other classes , it's work. So my question now is :What Is the best practice for using animation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, if your `<div class="hvr-grow">` is the first html element in your lightning component, it also becomes the `.THIS` component. So you must remove the space between `.THIS` and `.hvr-grow` in your css.

I just tested the below code and it's working:

```
<aura:component >
    <div class="hvr-grow">
        test
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**CSS**

```
.THIS.hvr-grow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
}
.THIS.hvr-grow:hover, .THIS.hvr-grow:focus, .THIS.hvr-grow:active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Comment: ok , understood .My div is in the  'aura:component' so in this case , from what i understand , the .THIS is the 'aura:component' and so i need a space after . for me it is working with spaces , without no.